# ArcGIS Annotation Font Symbol Collection

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-10.4, annotation

Is there a way in Arcpy, to loop through the symbol collection to get back some attributes of each item in the symbol collection list (symbol ID, symbol name, font size, etc.)?

I need to do this in arcpy, but what I'm talking about is the information that you see in ArcCatalog's Annotation tab of the Feature Class Properties dialog. There is a list box with the title "Symbol Collection". The symbol ID appears in parenthesis and right next to it is symbol name.